# LINQ: Write Expression with body to return IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have the following code:

```
Func<ObjectA, ObjectB> selector = item =>
{
    var b = new ObjectB();
    ...
    return b;
};

var result = items.Select(selector);
```

And this code returns `IEnumerable<ObjectB>` but I need `IQueryable<ObjectB>`

As I understood, I need to do `Expression`

If I do next:

```
Expression<Func<ObjectA, ObjectB>> selector = item =>
{
    var b = new ObjectB();
    ...
    return b;
};

var result = items.Select(selector);
```

It shows me error `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

How can I fix that?

Comment: What are you doing in those `...`? If it is not something that can be simplified to a single expression, you can't use expression trees.

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? It seems your `selector` simply is _no expresssion_, so it won't ever be transformable to sql or whatever queryprovider you want to use. So you probably want to use it on client-side (in memory), maybe something like `var result = items.AsEnumerable().Select(selector);` with your first version of  `selector`.

Comment: I want to improve performance and so I want to use IQueryable

Comment: What makes you think `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable` would affect your performance? This would only be a matter if the query provider could translate your "expression" into something that the db (or whatever backend there is) can perform instead of your app.

Comment: @RenéVogt, maybe, OP is trying to achieve [this](https://coderethinked.com/don-t-use-func-delegate-on-the-ef-entities/)